# Modifying class attribute by calling class method from inside decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-decorators, contextmanager

I have quite a few methods that requires opening some file (each method has different), doing some stuff, closing it. Althou it is possible to open and close a file within each method, I am wondering whether it is possible to do it through decorators so that a decorator could take method as a parameter which would load data into obj attribute that the decorated class is acting on.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

    def load_file(self):
        with open(self.fname, 'rb') as f:
            self.file_ = pickle.load(f)
    
    def do_some_work(self):
        self.load_file()
        ... # some calculation and so on
        delattr(self, 'file_')

    @loader(self.load_file)
    def do_some_work_decorated(self):
         ... # only some calculation and so on, file loading is done by the defined method in decorator
```

My question is whether this is even possible and are there better ways to approach it?

Comment: I see that you have an answer posted already for your question, but I really didn't think you've described what exactly you're trying to do (other than "trying to figure this out by decorating methods"). Is it the opening and processing and closing of files that you want to do with decorators? Could you pls elaborate?

Comment: @fountainhead: I think the question's pretty clear — the OP wants some common preprocessing to occur at the beginning of multiple methods and wonders if there's a way to do it with a decorator. I do agree that it seems like an odd question since doing so is a lot more work than just explicitly calling the methods at the beginning of those that need it — so perhaps it's an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do something similar to that, but you'd need to pass the *name* the method to the decorator because there's no `self` for it to refer to when it's used to decorate the method(s) — which happens when the class is defined not when the code in it is executed afterwards.

Here's what I mean:

```
import pickle

def loader(do_stuff):
    def decorator(method):
        def decorated(self, *args, **kwargs):
            getattr(self, do_stuff)()  # Call specified class method.
            return method(self, *args, **kwargs)  # Then call decorated method.
        return decorated
    return decorator


class Foo:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

    def load_file(self):
        with open(self.fname, 'rb') as f:
            self.file_ = pickle.load(f)

    def do_some_work(self):
        self.load_file()
        ... # some calculation and so on
        delattr(self, 'file_')

    @loader('load_file')
    def do_some_work_decorated(self):
        ... # only some calculation and so on, file loading is done by the defined method in decorator
        print(f'{self.file_}')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create a test file.
    with open('foo.pkl', 'wb') as outp:
        pickle.dump(42, outp)

    # See if decorator worked.
    foo = Foo('foo.pkl')
    foo.do_some_work_decorated()  # -> 42
```